# Unable to plot column in y axis in R

Tags: r, data-science

I have columns in R dataframe as

```
            StreetName              BeginTime
         wls-wilkeson17-45      2016-11-26 20:04:33
         wls-wilkeson17-46      2016-11-26 20:20:06
         wls-wilkeson17-49      2016-11-26 21:28:01
         wls-wilkeson17-46      2016-11-26 21:33:10
         wls-wilkeson17-43      2016-11-26 21:48:56
         wls-wilkeson17-46      2016-11-26 21:59:18
         wls-wilkeson17-47      2016-11-26 21:07:19
```

And type of "StreetName" column is "factor". When I am trying to plot this column in y or x axis in R it is showing some numeric values in axis like

```
2620.0 
2620.6
2621.1
2622.3 ......
```

[image]

But I wanted it should show all street names in axis. Can anyone please guide me in right direction?

Plot created by code:

```
plot(x = user_sig_all$BeginTime, y = user_sig_all$StreetName)
```

Comment: please include at least 5 to 10 rows of your data frame along with the code you are using to produce the plot in your question

Comment: How many rows are in StreetName?

Comment: There are 7 rows in total

Comment: Updated resulting graph also

Comment: Please also post the code you used to produce that plot.

Comment: The main reason this is not working as you wanted is because you are trying to plot a scatterplot of a categorical variable against a continuous variable where the categorical cannot be easily coerced into numeric. You can either make a barplot or a stripchart with labels, which are both better choices.

Comment: Thanks @useR for pointing in right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily by using `ggplot2`.

Try this:

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
StreetName             Date       Time
wls-wilkeson17-45      2016-11-26 20:04:33
wls-wilkeson17-46      2016-11-26 20:20:06
wls-wilkeson17-49      2016-11-26 21:28:01
wls-wilkeson17-46      2016-11-26 21:33:10
wls-wilkeson17-43      2016-11-26 21:48:56
wls-wilkeson17-46      2016-11-26 21:59:18
wls-wilkeson17-47      2016-11-26 21:07:19")
dat$BeginTime <- as.POSIXct(paste(dat$Date, dat$Time))
dat

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=BeginTime, y = StreetName)) + geom_point()
```

[image]